# Set disk quota for IIS Manager user

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, ftp

Is it possible to set disk quota for IIS manager user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, sorry.

Or: Quotas are not handled in IIS. Depending on the setup of the storage you could set on in the FIle Services Resource Manager and limit the disc share. I say depending because this is known not to work with - replication ;)